# exclude main www domain from cpanel wildcard subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added a subdomain `"*"` like `*.mydomain.com` to my cPanel account. with a directory name `subdomainsystem`.

Now every subdomain works fine and loading script from subdomainsystem directory and if I go to `www.mydomain.com` it was showing main root script (main site). But after few days if I go to `www.mydomain.com`, it is being considered as a subdomain as well.

Here is my `.htaccess` in root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?subdomain=%2&menu=$1 [QSA]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak regex to disallow `www` also before main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?subdomain=%2&menu=$1 [L,QSA]
```